# Not able to store an image using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I don't know where I have make a mistake in this program. I am not able to store the image retrived from database.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class kmpp
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fos=null;
        Connection con=null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","rock");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from image where name=?");
            ps.setString(1,"mohit");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                InputStream is=rs.getBinaryStream(2);
                fos=new FileOutputStream("F:/Documents and Settings/cboy/Desktop/New Folder/moh.jpg");
                int data;
                while((data=is.read())!=-1)
                {
                    fos.write(data);
                }
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        //is.close();
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception caught ");
        }
        //fos.close();
        //con.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The close() method of FileOutputStream doesn't flush() - I'd try that first.

Comment: Nice to see the code, but not enough detail to know what the problem is. How does it fail? What is the message it gives? Without knowing that it is pretty hard to help.

Comment: I do not know the image size. Generally You should not store the image on the database.instead place an entry of the image path or file link in a table column.

Answer (score 0):

The second column is blob or longraw? If it's blob try to use rs.getBlob(2).getBinaryStream() instead of rs.getBinaryStream(2).